# MS Chart axes are drawn trough data points

Tags: c#, graphics, mschart

I'm working with MS Charts, and somehow I can't figure out a way to draw the points on top of the y-axis. 
As you can see in the image below, the points at x = 0 (label 1998) are below the Y-axis. 
Does anyone recognize this problem? Has it something to do with order of prepaint and postpaint events?

[image: axis trough points]

EDIT: Test with custom drawn dots, only until the y-axis..
[image]

Comment: That is the normal behaviour. Do you actually have any paint events?

Comment: Yeah, in the OnPostPaint we draw our own Beziercurves

Comment: Well, then drawing the Points as well isn't that hard; you can use the same AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue); etc functions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `Chart` all `DataPoints` go **over** the `GridLines` but **under** the `Axes` and the `TickMarks`.

To paint them **over** the `Axes` as well you need to **owner draw** them in one of the `Paint` events.

This is simple if your `ChartType` is of type `Points`, `Spline` or `Line` and your `MarkerType` of `Circle` or `Rectangle`.

For most other types like `Column` or `Bar` etc this is a lot harder.

Here is a simple example for `Points`; pick a size you like better..!

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (chart1.Series.Count == 0) return;

    Axis AX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    Axis AY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    chart1.ApplyPaletteColors();
    foreach (Series s in chart1.Series)
        foreach (DataPoint dp in s.Points)
        {
           float x = (float )AX.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue);
           float y = (float )AY.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[0]);
           float w2 = 3.6f;
           using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.YellowGreen))
                  e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, 
                                                       x - w2, y - w2, w2 * 2f, w2 * 2f);
        }
}
```

[image][image]

I have suppressed the custom drawing for **some** points.

Comment: I've done this, but now I've the problem it draws only until the axis, at the left side of the y-axis you see the automatically drawn dot, at the right side of the y-axis my own custom drawn circle..

Comment: This sohuldn't be. Please compare your code with the added example above!

Comment: chartAreaRect was calculated so the graphics.Clip was set to these boundaries. But in your image the points on the axes are also drawn under?

Comment: No, __they are over but semitransparent__ in the image so you can see how they match the original points. Simply use an normal color and you'll see they are over!

Comment: thnx for the help! There's still something wrong in my own code, but I've seen it working now. If I comment out a part of my code it works.